# NextJS13 + React - Hovering on a button causes another button to execute the onClick event

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a client component in NextJs13 with two buttons: a download button and a back button.

The download is an actual html button, while the back one is a link from next/link that redirect to a previous page.

For the download I have a custom onClick handler that does some api calls to fetch the data and then uses router.push from next/navigation to download the data as a csv file.

After the first download, when I hover over the back button, the onClick event of the download button gets executed, causing multiple downloads. This happens only when the app is deployed. When testing it in localhost this does not happen.

I am using AWS Amplify for deploy.
The exact version of NextJs I am using is 13.4.19 with React version 18.2.0

This is the code for the two buttons

```
          <Button
            color="primary"
            onClick={handleClick}
            disabled={disableDownload}
          >
            <ArrowDownTrayIcon className="w-5 h-5 mr-2" /> Download
          </Button>
          <Button
            type="link"
            href={`/search/form?api_key=${apiKey}${newValues}`}
            color="secondary"
          >
            Go Back
          </Button>
```

and here is the code for the handleClick function

```
  const handleClick = async () => {
    setDisableDownload(true)
    const aziende = await getAziende( // Fetch the data to download
      searchCompanies?.aziende ?? [],
      searchCompanies?.nextpage
    )
    router.push(
      'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + convertToCsvLeadGeneration(aziende) // Download the data as csv file
    )
    setDisableDownload(false)
  }
```

When the custom component button is of type `link`, as said, I am using the Link component from next/naviagtion, here is the code

```
      <Link href={href ?? '#'} className={myClassName}>
        {children ?? ''}
      </Link>
```

I can't find what is wrong and why this happens. Can somebody help me?

EDIT1:

Full code for the button component:

```
'use client'

import React, { ReactNode, MouseEvent } from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import '../styles/Button.css'
import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge'

type ButtonProps = {
  color?: 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'danger' | 'warning' | 'success'
  type?: 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset' | 'link'
  children?: string | ReactNode
  href?: string
  onClick?: (event?: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void
  className?: string
  disabled?: boolean
  icon?: ReactNode
}

export default function Button({
  color = 'primary',
  type,
  href,
  onClick,
  children,
  className,
  disabled,
}: ButtonProps) {
  let defaultClassName = 'btn'
  let myClassName = ''
  if (color) {
    myClassName = twMerge(color ?? '', defaultClassName, className)
  } else {
    myClassName = twMerge(defaultClassName, className)
  }
  if (type === 'link') {
    return (
      <Link href={href ?? '#'} className={myClassName}>
        {children ?? ''}
      </Link>
    )
  }
  if (disabled && disabled === true) {
    myClassName = twMerge('disable', defaultClassName, className)
    return (
      <button className={myClassName} disabled={disabled}>
        {children ?? ''}
      </button>
    )
  }
  return (
    <button
      className={myClassName}
      type={(type as 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset') ?? 'button'}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      {children ?? ''}
    </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you add the full code for the <Button> component

Comment: @Matt added it!